# Akka scheduleOnce callback never called

Tags: scala, callback, akka, scheduler

I have a simple problem/bug, but I can't figure out what's happining. I want to use the ActorSystem scheuler to schedule a callback. The sample code is as follows:

```
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("system-test1")

system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(2 seconds)(() =>
                                         {
                                           println("Hi")
                                         })
```

However, nothing is printed to the console and although I have a debugger breakpoint in the println line, the debugger doesn't stop there. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(2 seconds)(() => { println("Hi") })
```

The above passes to the `scheduleOnce` method a function that takes zero arguments and returns `Unit`. The version of the `scheduleOnce` method that you're invoking doesn't take a function as a parameter; it takes a call-by-name parameter that is a `Unit`:

```
final def scheduleOnce(delay: FiniteDuration)(f: => Unit)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Cancellable
```

Therefore, simply pass in `println("Hi")`, which returns `Unit`:

```
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(2 seconds)(println("Hi"))
```

Comment: OMG! My bad... I always miss that :() => Unit is different that : => (callback vs by need). Thank you, you saved my day!